# Why would you restrict these characters within a password?

Tags: passwords, password-policy

A website restricts these characters from passwords: `# * ( ) %`

At a casual glance, it looks like they're not sanitizing data input to the database or hashing passwords, but I'm a hobbyist.

Should I contact the IT maintainer? This is a new site that was just launched to replace an old one within my industry.

Comment: "Should I contact ..." -- to what end?

Comment: The short answer is that there is no general reason to do so. This would be a question to ask the site's devs.